# How to avoid code repeatation in multiple components in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

In my angular application there are multiple components out of which , 2 components use almost same code except one component uses extraa button tags that has its own logic remaining code is almost same in both the components.

### Is there any way to reduce the code repeatation ?

- After opening my application default page opens that contains top div - mid 
  div and bottom div.
- in top div - there are few links clicking on these opens a new page (new 
  component) .
- Here if i click on a link in tom div, respective component page will open this 
  page is almost same as before containing top div, mid div, bottom div but some 
  extra links in top div.
- so template is almost same in both the components. so how to avoid copying the 
  same code in both components ?
- is there any way that i can put component1 template in components2 ? ( I cant 
  use selector because i need to ass some more links in top div in component2 )

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this.

One could be to combine the two components into one. Then pass in an input which determines whether the extra button tags should show.

```
<combined-component [showExtraButtons]="true"></combined-component>
```

And then to hide the extra buttons.

```
<combined-component [showExtraButtons]="false"></combined-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the exact case, but you might want look at this: [Generalizing Components](https://www.sparkbit.pl/generalizing-components-angular/)

In some cases it may be good to use composition pattern to reduce code duplication. You can create some `generic` component and pass extra content using angular transclusion.

Answer (score 0):

As what I understand from your current scenario you should use `@Input` decorator to pass the data between components to show or hide your component or use `*ngIf`

> Using *ngIf set the value of toShow from your ts.

`<div *ngIf="toShow"></div>`

> Using @Input in your ts file

`@Input() className: string = "display-block";`

> In your component

`<div [class]="className"></div>`

Comment: can you please tell me clearly, i didn't understand . using  component1 and componet2 as referaance.